# Handle Multiple Rrequests Simultaneously Android

Tags: android

For button in Android, I have implemented Click method in XML and set Click Listener in java class. Which method call for the button either XML or Click Listener. I went through the documentation but could not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnClickListener` in code will be used if both are set.

Comment: Thanks FD_. Got Cleared Now.